# Writing specific columns in collection into Excel - Blue Prism

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

I have extracted some data into a collection but the first 2 columns of the extracted data is empty. I only want to write data from the 3rd column onwards into the Excel sheet. Any suggestions on how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `Utility - Collection Manipulation` VBO to delete the two initial columns?

Comment: That worked, thanks! @esqew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is built in VBO provided `Uitility - Collection Manipulation`. You can delete the column by using `Delete Column` action or you can make use of `Split Collection` as well.

If there is a requirement of deleting multiple columns, you will have to loop and use `Delete Column` action, as `Delete Column` action accepts only one column at a time.

Where as for `Split Collection` action you need to define the 2 templates.

- First template will hold the required columns
- Second template will hold the other columns

As an output of `Split Collection` action, you'll get two collection respectively.